# probability of obtaining at least one 6 if it is known that all three dice showed different faces

Tags: probability

Three dice are rolled. What is the probability of obtaining at least one 6 if it is known that all three dice showed different faces? The answer is 0.5. Could you give a hint?

Comment: I calculated the probability of the three dice showing different faces and got 5/9.

Comment: How many ways are there to choose three different values?  How many of them contain a $6$?

Comment: Don't worry about the probability of the three dice showing different faces. You are given that that occurred. Just focus on the situation after given all three faces are different.

Comment: Well, this might not sould convincing but there are 3 numbers showing and 3 numbers not showing.  Any outcome is equally likely.  So six being one of the numbers showing is equally likely as six not being one of the numbers showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be unnecessarily thourough.  There are $6*5*4=120$ ways for the faces to be different.  (An arbitrary first die can have any face, the arbitrary second can have any of the five remaining, etc.)

There are $3(1*5*4)=60$ ways for one of the faces to be a $6$. (The face that is a 6, must be a six, the second can be any of 5 and the third any of 4, and there are 3 chooses for which die is $6$.  So Probability is $60/120 = 1/2$.

2)  The probability of the first die being a six is $1/6$.  The probability of the second die being a six, and the first die not being a six, given the dies are different is $5/6*1/5 = 1/6$.  So probability of one of the first two dice is six is $1/6 + 1/6 = 1/3$  The probability of the third die being six and neither of the first two, given that all there are different is $2/3*1/4 = 1/6$.  So the probability of one the faces being six given they are all different is $1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2$.

3)All combinations of different numbers are equally likely.  $3$ numbers appear.  $3$ do not.  Each is equally likely so that a six appears (or not) is 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

To justify the answer formally you could use what you know about conditional probability. In particular:

Let $S$ be the event that at least one six occurs, and $D$ that all three dice show different faces. The outcome of our experiment is a triple $(a,b,c)$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are the faces showed by the first, the second and the third dice respectively. There are $N = 6^3$ such triples. In addition, there are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$ ways of choosing $(a,b,c)$ such that no face is repeated therein, so $P(D) = \frac {6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{N}$. Let us now consider the event $S \cap D$ (i.e. one dice shows six, and all of them have different outcomes); there are 3 ways to choose which dice shows six, and $5 \cdot 4$ to select the faces of the other two, in total: $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$ cases, which yields $P(S \cap D) = \frac{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{N} > 0$. Finally, we obtain the probability  in question:
$$P(S|D) = \frac {P(S \cap D)}{P(D)} = \frac {3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4} = 0.5.$$

Comment: I edited my post, providing more details. Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, it's OK now. I haven't checked whether it is correct, but it's definitely an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the three dice show different faces after being rolled, then surely three different numbers are obtained. What is the probability that these include the number $6$?

Answer (score 1):

If all three dice are different, imagine the 6 numbers from 1 to 6. Three of them have been rolled and three have not. So each number has a 50% chance of being one of the three rolled since no number has an inherent advantage over the others.

Comment: But can I calculate it using a formula?

Comment: One way would be $\frac{\text{# of ways to pick 3 numbers with one being a 6}}{\text{# of ways to pick 3 numbers}}$ which would be $\frac{5\choose2}{6\choose3}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$